# Is there a way to search for folder (directory) in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I can press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F</kbd> in PhpStorm, and I will get a window with search options. I can search for particular string in all project files, I can leave "Text to find" field empty and put name of the file I'm looking for in "File mask(s)" field to find a particular file, but is there a way to find a folder by its name?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In `Find in Path` dialog (<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F</kbd>) -- No.

But you can use `Navigate | File...` for that (<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + N</kbd> on Windows/Linux using Default keymap)

[image]

**The key is** to use path separator `/` to denote that the previous part was a folder.

Same as actual search for file name: the directory name can be partial: `phpd/` will match `phpdoc/` if that the only folder. Similar with capital letters: `mff/` will match `MyFavouriteFolder/`.

Comment: Note to other users: you may need to include the "/" mark for it to show up on your list.

Comment: Looks like if you use search for partial folder name like `MyFavoriteDirecto/` and add trailing slash you will find `MyFavoriteDirectory`

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: On Mac `Cmd + Shift + O`

Comment: When I want to find a directory named `migrations` the only way I can find it is to use `migrations/` meaning I have to know exactly what I'm searching for.  `migration/` and `migrat/` return no results.  'migrat\w+/' with regex checked also doesn't return any directories, but does return other results such as strings that contain a match.  Ironically, the `Directory` mode returns no matched on directories in any case I tried.

Comment: @AlphaCactus TBH -- No solid idea what you are talking about (what regex, which `Directory` mode) -- but the search from my answer works just fine here: https://postimg.org/image/1lodx2l2q3/ . Possibly your indexes are corrupted or something... if so -- try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE.

Answer (score 0):

File or Folder right click > Mark Directory as > Excluded

Only blue directories will be searched

[image: Only blue directories will be searched]