# Efficient way to organize View files in Laravel 5.3 when coding with PhpStorm

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpstorm, filenames

I don't know if this question qualifies to be in SO, but since PhpStorm became de facto *the* IDE to develop in Laravel framework, this could be helpful to many of us. Since file naming in Laravel is a big deal, I was wandering what would be a proper/efficient/logical way to name **View** files.

Lets say I declare all my routes in `web.php`. I have multiple tables, all named as *word in plural* like `articles`. So I have `Article` model and `ArticleController` resource controller. Controller consist of standard RESTful and nonstandard routes.

The way I wanted to name my View files is pretty much straightforward and logical, eg:

- for `home` in `web.php` I have `/resources/views/home.blade.php` and define it with `view('home')`
- for `index` in `ArticleController` I have `/resources/views/articles/index.blade.php` and define it with `view('articles.index')`
- for `show` in `ArticleController` I have `/resources/views/articles/show.blade.php` and define it with `view('articles.show')`etc...

Problem arise when I want to use famous PhpStorm <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> *open by file search*, I get filenames with the same filename, like `show.blade.php`. As far as I know, there is no way to search by a path name...

So, I decided to rename my filenames to `articles_show.blade.php`, `articles_index.blade.php`, but pretty soon I my `views` folder was overcrowded. I have considered `articles/articles_show.blade.php` pattern, but it's not following DRY principle and look ugly when defined.

**Do any of you managed to develop a solution for efficient and logical naming convention? How do YOU organize your view files?**

**P.S.** I still use original pattern for vendor views, like `auth/login.blade.php`, `auth/register.blade.php`. Layouts files also follows that pattern: `layouts/app.blade.php` (popular layout name), `layouts/header.blade.php`, `layouts/footer.blade.php`. But it's obvious, these filenames will not be repeated, so no problem with search function. I want to also mention, that for most tables/controllers/models I have a special `loop` view file, that is not bound to any function or route, and named by established pattern, like `articles_loop.blade.php`.

Comment: *"As far as I know, there is no way to search by a path name... "* you are wrong. Just use `/` to denote that previous part is a path. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27941532/783119

Comment: @LazyOne what you have there is a *FOLDER* search by a name. FYI, folder is essentially a file. You **can** find a file `articles_show.blade.php` by typing "ar sh" in the box. But **this will yield 0 results** for articles/show.blade.php even if you prefix any of the keys with "/".

Comment: `ar/sh` does the job fine for me. **UPDATE** As I see you have figured it out yourself already (the answer was not there when I did this comment)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you **can** search for a filename by a path! Kudos to **@LazyOne**, since he pushed me in [the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27941532/783119).

So, in order to search for a *filename* within a *path* using a *partial* match, all you need to do is *suffix* a partial path name with **"/"** and type in a partial of your filename.

So in order to find `/resources/views/articles/show.blade.php`, you can put either:

- `ar/sh`
- `vi/ow`
- `ar/shbl` (notice how I used two partial `sh` and `bl` to find `show.blade.php` without any separator whatsoever).

etc..