# How in PhpStorm to open file by relative path of the file?

Tags: phpstorm

Using git for my project I got relative path of files of the project, like :

```
routes/breadcrumbs.php 
resources/views/newdesign/layouts/current_user.blade.php
...
```

and when I want in PhpStorm 2019.2.3 to open 1 file from the listing above
menu item Files->Open does not help me, as full file path must be copied in it dialog.

If there is a way to open file by its relative path with paste from clipboard?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like they are part of the project. In such case: `Navigate | File` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are relative paths and therefore I assume that those files are already part of the project.

In such case `Navigate | File` should do the job for you just fine.

[image]

[image]

P.S. It can even locate/navigate to folders: just end it with `/` -- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27941532/783119.